# ng-change not working on text box backspace button press

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

ng-change even not firing on text box backspace button press.

ng-change works fine on  changing  the value example pressing numbers or any character from keyboard but not on backspace button press

Comment: show some code, it will help to understand problem. or can you make fiddle?

Answer (score 2):

try like this.

```js
var app = angular.module("app",[])
app.controller('ctrl',['$scope', function($scope){
     
  
  $scope.test = function(model){
    console.log(model);
    
    }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<div class="item item-checkbox">
   <input type="text" ng-model="model" ng-change="test(model)">
   {{model}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The ngChange expression is only evaluated when a change in the input value causes a new value to be committed to the model.

It will not be evaluated:

- if the value returned from the $parsers transformation pipeline has
  not changed
- if the input has continued to be invalid since the model will stay
  null
- if the model is changed programmatically and not by a change to the
  input 
  ngChange will nor get fired when you press spacebar, if you enter character or number followed by space then it will get fired.

Please send code or example so that I can help you more....
Refer: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange